# How do I fork a process that doesn't die when shell exits?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, nohup, forking

If I run emacs from the shell:

```
$ emacs foo &
```

and then kill that shell, emacs dies.

How can I run a command so that it will not die when the shell dies?

I found references to nohup, but that does not seem to help:

```
$ nohup emacs foo &
```

still kills emacs when shell dies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not mention if this is running as an X app or a console app.

If it's as a console app, of course it needs to close.  You got rid of it's input/output, more technically the (pseudo) tty it was on.  It's very unlikely this is what you meant, so let's assume you're talking about an X app.

`nohup` should work, not sure why it isn't.  When the shell closes, it sends `SIGHUP` to all processes in its process group.  nohup tells the command to ignore SIGHUP.

You can also try setsid, which disconnects the process from the process group

```
alias emacs='setsid emacs'
```

Or add `disown` after `&`

Comment: Ah, great setsid works.

Sorry about not being clear. Yes I'm referring to X apps that do not actually run in the shell. Basically, I want to start up emacs (or any other process) from the shell, but I don't want it in any way tied to the shell. I'm just starting it there for convenience.

Answer (score 48):

The most reliable method appears to be:

```
(setsid emacs &)
```

This uses `( &)` to fork to background, and `setsid` to detach from the controlling tty.

You can put this in a shell function:

```
fork() { (setsid "$@" &); }

fork emacs
```

---

The possibilities are:

- The `disown` builtin command:

  ```
  emacs &
  disown $!
  ```

  `&` acts as command separator, and `disown` will default to the most recent job, so this can be shortened to:

  ```
  emacs & disown
  ```
- Double-`fork()`:

  ```
  (emacs &)
  ```

  Commands inside parentheses `(` `)` are run in a separate shell process.
- `setsid`, as suggested by Rich, might be the best choice, because it unsets the controlling TTY of the process by creating a new [session](http://man.cx/credentials):

  ```
  setsid emacs
  ```

  However, it is also a little unpredictable - it will only `fork()` to background if it is the leader of a process group (which won't happen if `setsid` is used in a `sh` script, for example; in such occassions it will merely become resistant to Ctrl-C.)

Comment: Great! these all work for me. Nice to have some more tools in my arsenal.

Comment: Hm... would `(exec emacs)` work?

Comment: @Hello: It would be no different from just `(emacs)`. If the subshell is given a single command, the `exec` is implied, at least in case of `bash`. Same applies to `bash -c 'foo'` versus `bash -c 'exec foo'`. (However, note that emacs *itself* may be detaching from the terminal; gvim, for example, does this. It is better to test with a program with known behavior.)

Comment: Great to learn of the double-fork technique; thanks!

Comment: Found this while trolling to fix an issue of my own. The (setsid emacs &) worked for me. Thanks for a well written answer.

Comment: For the record, this by any means is not the well-known double fork for daemonization.

Comment: By the way, does anybody know how to combine this with something like `&>/dev/null` to get rid of the outpur in the console too? I tried nad it seems to mess up with the process.

Answer (score 5):

Check you shell settings. You can also try [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) instead of `nohup`.

Comment: Screen allows you to get back into the process later with `screen -r` if you use `Ctrl-A Ctrl-D` to disconnect it before logging out.

Comment: This is a very good point. I needed the opposite, i.e. forking a subshell and proceed with other tasks without waiting for its completion, but `screen -d -m sh -c "{do stuff } exit"` makes much more sense.