# service started from sh script stops when sh script

Tags: linux, centos, services, sh

I have service named "router" that is able to receive http requests.
I decided to write sh script that will periodically check health of router service.
if something is wrong then it will restart it.

The problem:
if router was started with this script, then if this script is terminated, then router service is also terminated.
strange thing is that simple one-line sh script that simply does "service router restart" - works fine (so it restarts the service and closes immediately and everything is fine)

i suppose the reason is somewhere in loop or some bash if things.
script code attached...
Thanks for help!

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
   STATUS=$(curl --silent localhost:80/test)
   if [ "$STATUS" != "OK" ]
   then
    echo "problems: $STATUS".
    service router restart
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Related: [(1)](http://superuser.com/questions/190827/how-do-i-keep-jobs-running-after-logout), [(2)](http://superuser.com/questions/124399/keep-a-program-running-after-closing-a-console-after-the-program-has-started).

Comment: That is weird. Try putting a `continue` after `service router restart` to see if it works then to try to isolate the problem. `service` should fork off the process handling and return once the service has restarted, so all I can think of is that you have written the `/etc/init.d/router` script in a bad way. Post that script as well for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the process of bash script execution:

1. Bash forks a child, that runs another bash.
2. This child bash interprets the script, forking child and executing programs as needed.

All programs you run in the script, has this child bash as the controlling terminal.
So, now if the child bash terminates all programs normally terminate.

Since child bash doesn't return until the script exits, you cannot work on parent bash.
So you might need to run the child bash (that means the script) in background. That
lets you continue your work. Background bash doesn't terminate (unless you say or there is some fault).