# Make imagemagick's `display` exit at terminal, preserving the window (single instance mode)

Tags: linux, command-line, display, window, imagemagick

When I use `imagemagick`'s `display` from command line, say:

```
$ display -density 150 test1.pdf
```

... then `display` locks in the command line, until you exit the window (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in terminal).

However, what I'd like to do, is when the above command is ran in terminal, then `display` would both start the window, *and* at the same time exit; then I could quickly press up arrow in terminal, and edit the settings (like `-density`), and repeat the now modified command line - which would likewise now exit, and the window would show the newly requested image.

This is similar to how `scite` has a "single instance mode" (see [How to load new documents in a single instance of SciTE](http://ask.metafilter.com/16453/How-to-load-new-documents-in-a-single-instance-of-SciTE)): when it is set up, you can say `scite filename` on the command line; `scite` then exits in terminal - while it opens the file as new tab (so you can quickly open files on command line by using `bash` history and up arrow). Now, I wouldn't expect `display`'s GUI to have tabs, but I think it should be possible to somehow have `display`'s window replace the content it displays upon a command...

Is what I want possible with `imagemagick`'s `display` - and if so, how?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fork a process that doesn't die when shell exits?](http://superuser.com/questions/172043/how-do-i-fork-a-process-that-doesnt-die-when-shell-exits)

Comment: Many thanks for that, @grawity - I tried `setsid` before my `display` command line, and it indeed does release the terminal - but then, how do I communicate with the running instance of `display` (e.g. to tell it to load a new image)? Am also looking now into coding a custom solution using an API: [linux - ImageMagick API for command-line GUI application interface to `display` - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663246/imagemagick-api-for-command-line-gui-application-interface-to-display). Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, just came up with a (*very crude - no mouse interaction, no anything*) script example using ImageMagick's Perl API, which demonstrates what I wanted done with `display` - so I thought I may just as well post about it here. The example is given in this answer: [ImageMagick API for command-line GUI application interface to `display` - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663246/imagemagick-api-for-command-line-gui-application-interface-to-display).

Hope I get to eventually read about how to do this with ImageMagick's `display`, though `:)`

Cheers!