# What is double forking?

Tags: bash

[How do I fork a process that doesn't die when shell exits?](https://superuser.com/a/172476/387658) talks about "double forking":

> - Double-`fork()`:
>
>   ```
>   (emacs &)
>   ```
>
>   Commands inside braces `(` `)` are run in a separate shell process.

Could you explain why that would make any difference compared to a simple `emacs &`. What would be the point of running it in a subshell environment in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> Could you explain why that would make any difference compared to a
>   simple `emacs &`.

`(emacs &)` runs a subshell which then runs `emacs &` inside it, which means that its `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are tied to the subshell instead.  It becomes double-forked and will survive the initial shell (where `(emacs &)` was run) dying.  Running only `emacs &` will keep the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` tied to the initial shell.

`emacs` is actually a bad example for this because the GUI version will not care that it lost its `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.  You can try with `(ls -R / &); exit` and then grep for it to see that it is still running.  *Edits welcome for a better example than `ls`.*

> What would be the point of running it in a subshell environment in
>   the first place?

To detach it completely from the initial shell (see above).